# Can I make an element "unfindable" from the DOM by redefining the native functions?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, redefinition

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
       <div id="myDiv"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

By redefining some native JavaScript functions, can I make `myDiv` unfindable?

For example, I can do:

```
window.HTMLDocument.prototype.getElementById = (function() {
  var oldefinition = window.HTMLDocument.prototype.getElementById;

  return function() {
    var returnValue = oldefinition.apply(this, arguments);
    if (returnValue && returnValue.id === 'myDiv') {
      return oldefinition.call(this, 'blablabla');
    } else {
      return returnValue;
    }
  }
})();
```

and I can do the same for the other functions such as:

- `querySelector`
- `querySelectorAll`
- `getElementsByTagName`
- `getElementsByClassName`
- etc.

This works, but the div is still available by calling:

```
document.body.children[0]
```

Then is there a way to make my div unfindable, that is, can I redefine the value of the `children` field?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Not exactly what you meant, but...... you could remove it from the DOM.  Can't find what doesn't exist!

Comment: I'm trying to hack a code for a university project and would like to know if this way is walkable. Unfortunately I can't remove the element.

Comment: I don't want to draw a definite conclusion on this, but if the browser is able to find the element to display, then anyone is. So if you can not remove it from the DOM, then anyone can access it on the DOM.

Comment: I feel like this is possible, but the approach that comes to mind is extremely verbose and detrimental to performance... basically, wrap every DOM API with a `Proxy()` that uses traps to conceal the real DOM.

Comment: _"that is, can I redefine the value of the children field?"_ - that alone won't do you much good ... body still has a firstChild, or a lastChild that in turn has previousSiblings, etc. pp. I think you would have to disable/"overwrite" nearly every property that references other elements in the DOM tree (and you still want me to be able to find those, after all you already implemented anything-but versions of the other query methods) in any way ...

Comment: @VanDir if you want to see what the approach I'm thinking of looks like, @ me in a comment here and I'll work on that tonight.

Comment: Instead of hiding the element by "erasing" it from `document.body.children` and other accessor properties, maybe it would be possible to wrap the element in a proxy that tells you it's something else.  You wouldn't need to affect sibling accessors, just that one element.  So, `document.body.children[0].id` might say "fruitcake" and `document.body.children[0].tagName == "span".  Users would "find" the element, but not realize they found it.

Comment: Can you alter the HTML? You could remove the `id` of the element and instead make it another property, such as `id2`. That way *you* could still find the element, but chances are no one else would know to look for that property.

Comment: Thanks all guys. I would like to make the element unfindable in any way (not only by id). I think that I have to override all the fields that you described (children, firstChild, lastChild, etc.) plus all the search functions (querySelector, getElementById, etc.). I will try this approach (thanks to Amy answer) but I'm intersted to the Proxy approach too. @PatrickRoberts. Thanks again!

Comment: [This page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) appears to list every API you must override in order to hide an element.

Comment: Having started attempting my approach using proxies, I found out it will take a few days to implement even just a couple exemplary bindings. I'll post an example of patching [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) (to deal with [`ParentNode.prototype.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)) this weekend when I have more time.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is an attempt that seems to work okay - at least, with regards to `document.body.children`.  I tested a variation of the following code on MDN's website to hide all script tags that are immediate children of the document body.

The way this works is we tell `document.body` to use a new property called `children`.  We then return the original contents of `children`, minus the ones we don't want.

```
var oldchildren = document.body.children;
Object.defineProperty(document.body, 'children', { 
    get() { 
        var lst = [];
        for (var item of oldchildren) {
            if (!(item.tagName === "div" && item.id === 'myDiv'))
                lst.push(item);
        }
        return lst;
    } 
});
```

Any code that references `document.body.children` *after* this code runs won't see the `div`.  This code might cause other code on your site to misbehave.

Comment: it would probably be better to define `lst` as `Object.create(HTMLCollection)`, but of course when I was testing that, doing things like attempting to iterate, or simply checking the `length` accessor property threw `TypeError`, so... guess this is okay